# Money and Happiness

Tags: sources-mekorot, money, simchah-joy-happiness

I heard from someone that money buys you happiness. Is that true?

What's the Torah's perspective on both money and happiness?

Answer (score 2):

Ecclesiastes (Kohelet) 5, 12:

> יֵ֚שׁ רָעָ֣ה חוֹלָ֔ה רָאִ֖יתִי תַּ֣חַת הַשָּׁ֑מֶשׁ עֹ֛שֶׁר שָׁמ֥וּר לִבְעָלָ֖יו לְרָעָתֽוֹ׃ ‏
>
> There is a grievous evil which I have seen under the sun, namely, riches kept by the owner thereof to his hurt;

Avot 4, 1:

> איזה הוא עשיר--השמח בחלקו, שנאמר "יגיע כפיך, כי תאכל; אשריך, וטוב לך" (תהילים קכח,ב):  "אשריך", בעולם הזה; "וטוב לך", לעולם הבא.
>
> Who is rich? One who is satisfied with his lot. As is stated (Psalms 128:2): "If you eat of toil of your hands, fortunate are you, and good is to you"; "fortunate are you" in this world, "and good is to you" in the World to Come.

Prophet need to be rich, see Rambam 8 Chapters:

> וְדַע, שֶׁכָּל נָבִיא לֹא נִתְנַבֵּא אֶלָּא אַחַר שֶׁיִּהְיוּ לוֹ כָּל הַמַּעֲלוֹת הַשִּׂכְלִיּוֹת, וְרֹב מַעֲלוֹת הַמִּדּוֹת וְהַחֲזָקוֹת שֶׁבָּהֶן, וְהוּא אָמְרָם: "אֵין הַנְּבוּאָה שׁוֹרָה, אֶלָּא עַל חָכָם, גִּבּוֹר וְעָשִׁיר". וְ"חָכָם"- הוּא כּוֹלֵל כָּל הַמַּעֲלוֹת הַשִּׂכְלִיּוֹת בְּלִי סָפֵק, וְ"עָשִׁיר" - הוּא מִמַּעֲלוֹת הַמִּדּוֹת, רְצוֹנִי לוֹמַר: ‏הַהִסְתַּפְּקוּת, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהֵם קוֹרְאִים הַמִּסְתַּפֵּק - עָשִׁיר. וְהוּא אָמְרָם בְּגֶדֶר הֶעָשִׁיר: "אֵיזֶהוּ עָשִׁיר? - הַשָּׂמֵחַ בְּחֶלְקוֹ", רְצוֹנוֹ לוֹמַר: שֶׁיַּסְפִּיק לוֹ בְּמַה שֶּׁהִמְצִיא לוֹ זְמַנּוֹ, וְלֹא יִכְאַב בְּמַה שֶּׁלֹא הִמְצִיא לוֹ. וְכֵן "גִּבּוֹר" - הוּא גַםכֵּן בְּמַעֲלוֹת הַמִּדּוֹת, רְצוֹנִי לוֹמַר: שֶׁיַנְהִיג כֹּחוֹתָיו כְּפִי הַדַּעַת וְהָעֵצָה, כְּמוֹ שֶׁבֵּאַרְנוּ בַּפֶּרֶק הַחֲמִישִי, וְהוּא אָמְרוֹ: "אֵיזֶהוּ גִּבּוֹר? - הַכּוֹבֵשׁ אֶת יִצְרוֹ". ‏
>
> Prophet needs **to be rich but following the *above* definition**.

### Conclusion: Happiness is money but money is not happiness.

```
 It was a joke of language, I called wealth ("money") To consider himself lucky (or~ happy),  
but money (stricto sensu) is not happiness (יש עושר שמור לבעליו לרעתו)
```

Comment: Your conclusion does not seem to be supported by your sources.  .........עָשִׁיר הוּא מִמַּעֲלוֹת הַמִּדּוֹת, רְצוֹנִי לוֹמַר: הַהִסְתַּפְּקוּת, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהֵם קוֹרְאִים הַמִּסְתַּפֵּק - עָשִׁיר

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok It was a jocke of language, To know how to be happy is called wealth ("money") but money (stricto sensu) is not happiness (יש עושר שמור לבעליו לרעתו). I was convinced to be clear. Sorry.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok fixed

Answer (score 0):

If the owner of the money self-identifies with the money this is evil for him and for the world.

If the owner of the money understands the constructive value of money and uses it thus this is good for him and for the world.

Pen oresh ve'ganavti, pen esba ve'kachashti.

Not having money at all can totally destroy a person's personality in the concessions they feel they have to make to anyone who will help them survive.

Comment: How do you know this?